# Customize mouse pointer with css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want change div mouse pointer icon when div:hover active with my own png icon. how can I do that with css ,jquery, javasript ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor#Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS :

```
#yourDivId:hover {
   cursor:url('yourPath.png'), crosshair;
}
```

Note that it's better to provide a fallback (separate values with commas). Here `crosshair` will be used if `yourPath.png` can't be used.